# I was removed as inventor on a patent after leaving the company. Do I have any rights?

Tags: inventorship

I worked for a company in a senior tech leadership role and was responsible for their patent applications. I worked with patent attorney to write 3 applications, one of which I was a named inventor on.

I left the company a couple of years ago, somewhat acrimoniously, and before the final applications were submitted, but after the initial registration. I have subsequently discovered that the patent that I was named inventor on has been granted, but the inventor names have been changed to the CEO's partner, an employee in the company, and I have been removed along with others who have also left.

What is the position for the inventorship? It seems wrong that this is allowed, although I understand I have no claim on the patent as inventor because the assignee was, and still is, the company.

Comment: Wouldn't this implicitly invalidate the patent altogether?

Comment: Even when listed as inventor, you don't have any rights to that patent. Most likely patent assignee is the company.

Answer (score 2):

If you still have any written documents or any recordings or even an email wherein this can be proved that you were the inventor of the invention, then, YES, you can invalidate that application/draft!

As far as I know you can take it for legal course as well provided you have a concrete proof !

Good Luck !

Comment: I do have documents; I have the original draft with my name on it, which was submitted to "hold the date". It looks like the UK Patent office charges £400 to submit a challenge!

Comment: The original inventor of the patent remains and the employer cannot change that. If you have proof, you can take legal action against the employer.